# Connecting Postgresql db with Sails.js

Tags: postgresql, npm, sails.js, psql

I am brand-new to Sails and I'm looking to build my first application in javascript land! I am currently trying to connect my sails application to a postgresql database and I want to make sure that I am doing this correctly.

I started by creating a postgresql db with dbName, userName, password. I have added all this information into my `connections.js` file:

```
somePostgresqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '<username>', // optional
    password: '<password>', // optional
    database: '<databasename>' //optional
  }
```

I want to be sure I can migrate and perform all operations on my own so my `models.js` is set to `migrate: safe`. I ran `npm install sails-postgresql`. Now, to my understanding if I have migrate set to safe I will need the `sails-db-migrate` module (https://github.com/building5/sails-db-migrate). I followed this module step by step. I generated a `User` model by running `sails generate api user`. After this I ran `grunt db:migrate`. After all this, I check my `psql` database and no `User table` has been created. I know there is something I am missing, or maybe there is a more simple way to see if my postgresql db is connected.

Any advice or suggestions on how I should approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect my PSQL DB to my application by simply:

1. creating db in psql
2. configuring it in sails `app/connections.js`
3. running `npm install sails-postgresql`
4. Adding to `config/env/development.js`:

   models: {
   connection: 'somePostgresqlServer'
   }
5. running `sails generate api user`
6. sails lift
7. When asked for migration mode I chose options 2 which is `alter`
8. Opened up `psequal` and sure enough there was my new user table.

I'm not sure which of these actually triggered it to working from adding my db name to development.js, leaving off a PW on my DB, or changing migration mode to alter. But these steps helped it to connect. Will look further into.